# Add two large number using array

Tags: c++

sorry for my english.
I wrote a programm that add two large numbers.
Number 1 is read from file data1.in, the same with the second, data2.in.
The problem was when I tryed to add `68925579999999999990+79925579999999999990` I am getting the wrong result:48951159999999999980.
using python to add these numbers I have got 148851159999999999980.
Where I got wrong ??

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include<math.h>

int n = 0;
int m = 0;
const int zerou = 9000;


//using namespace std;

void zero(int*a)
{
     for(int i = 0;i<zerou;i++)
    a[i]=0;
}



void zero(int*a,int*b)
{
    for(int i = 0;i<zerou;i++)
    a[i]=b[i]=0;
}


void rebuild(int* a)
{
    int temp[9000];
    zero(temp);
    int i;

    int delta = abs(m-n)+1;//k1 -dim a
    for(i = delta;i<n+delta;i++)
    {
        temp[i] = a[i-delta];
        a[i-delta] = 0;
    }
    n += delta;
    for(i =0;i<n;i++)
    a[i] = temp[i];


}



void rebuildS(int* a)
{
    int temp[9000];
    zero(temp);
    int i;

    int delta = abs(m-n)+1;//k1 -dim a
    for(i = delta;i<m+delta;i++)
    {
    temp[i] = a[i-delta];
    }

    m += delta;
    for(i =0;i<m;i++)
    a[i] = temp[i];
}


void citirea(int* ar){
    ifstream f;

    f.open("data1.in");
    int data;
    while (f>>data){
    ar[n++] = data;
    }
    f.close();
}

void citirea_(int* ar){
    ifstream f("data2.in");
    int data;
    while (f>>data){
    ar[m++] = data;
    }
    f.close();
}

/*
void perDig(int*a, int*b,int *t,int i)
{
*t += (a[i]+b[i])/10;
a[i] = (a[i]+b[i]+*t)%10;

}*/


void adunarea(int*a, int* b)
{
    int transport = 0;
    int sum;

    for(int i = n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum = a[i]+b[i]+transport;
        //sum = perDig(a,b,transport,i);
        if(sum >9)
        {
            transport = (sum)/10;
            sum %=10;
          }
          a[i] = sum;

    }


}



int main()
{
    int a[9000],b[9000];
    zero(a,b);

    citirea(a);
    citirea_(b);

    if(n > m)
        rebuildS(b);

    else if(m > n)
         rebuild(a);
     adunarea(a,b);


ofstream rez;
rez.open("data.out");
for(int i = 0;i<m;i++)
{
 rez<<a[i]<<" ";

}        

rez.close();
cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?  Or C, for that matter?

Comment: `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` do not have .h extensions. In fact, none of the standard headers introduced in C++ have an extension.

Comment: If you only have troubles with adding 2 numbers, you shouldn't post your whole source-code, but only the most neccessary parts

Comment: @chris correct, he is including the c-Headers, which is possible in c++

Comment: @maja, There are no C headers for those two, only ones that actually exist in C.

Comment: @chris ooh, right. Strange that it still compiles

Comment: If you really need so big numbers I'd reccomend you to use bn from [openSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html).

Comment: I guess the variable-type `unsigned long long` should solve the Problem. But I can't even find the addition in his code.

Comment: "We don't accept 'code-dump, how fix' questions here. 'What's wrong with my code' is not a problem statement."

Comment: there is somethink with carry

Comment: addition starting here void adunarea(int*a, int* b)
{

Comment: @maja: he's using old style c++ headers. for the matter, this is example how to take a simple problem and make it complex.

Comment: 489511(5)9999999999980
(5) -wrong digit; i've used python to check the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your answer.
if (!sum > 9) you don't zero the transport, so numbers carry forever.
You are going to be one digit short because you add N digits and don't account for an Nth+1 digit in the answer if transport != 0.

You have a bigger problem, though.  You don't know how to debug the code yourself.  If in doubt, make the program tell you each step it performs, and read what it says, and see where it goes wrong.  Knowing how to do this is worth more than 10 correct versions of your code.

```
void adunarea(int*a, int* b)
{
    int transport = 0;
    int sum;

    for(int i = n;i>=0;i--)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " + " << b[i] << " + " << transport << endl;
        sum = a[i]+b[i]+transport;
        if(sum >9)
        {
            transport = (sum)/10;
            sum %=10;
        }
        a[i] = sum;
        cout << " = " << sum << " ( " << transport << " )" << endl;
    }
}
```

All I've done is add two print statements, and with that and the correct answer you can look for the first incorrect digit and see absolutely everything about how the wrong digit was made, and then fix it.

Comment: There are a number of other problems.  If you're just learning C++ (or programming), you will want to learn proper technique.  So some of the things wrong with the code as posted are:

    1. formatting - pick a style and use it consistently.  It will make your code easier to read and debug.
    2. global variables - try to avoid them.  
    3. "magic numbers" - you defined a constant `zerou` which is good, but then used `9000` many places in the code.
    4. no useful comments - comments help you (and others) understand the code. write them in your native language or English

Good luck!